# Getting a switch to fire when selecting a new item in a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

Fair warning, I'm a c# (and programming in general) noob, so I'm sorry if this comes across as overly simple.

I'm trying to make it so that when I select a new item in a list box it instantly updates a couple of variables and writes them to a couple of labels that I have set up and changes the image in a picture box. As this is for a university course I do have a stipulation that it needs to use switch statement. I've written some code but it doesn't really do anything. I think I'm having trouble with getting the event to fire. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void WorkshopSelector_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int lPrice = 150;
            int sPrice = 1000;
            int day = 3;
            int cPrice = day * lPrice;
            int tPrice = cPrice + sPrice;


        }

        private void lbx_city_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs f, ref int lPrice, ref int sPrice, ref int day, int cPrice, int tPrice)
        {
            string city = lbx_city.Text;
            switch (city)
            {
                case "AUS":
                    lbx_city.SelectedIndex = 1;
                    {
                        lPrice = 150;
                        lbl_price_city.Text = cPrice.ToString();
                        lbl_price_total.Text = tPrice.ToString();
                        pbx_img_city.Image = Week_2_B.Properties.Resources.CITY_Aus;
                    }
```

Comment: Your function seems to have a few extra parameters (see [ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)). How are you setting the event handler?

Comment: I'll be honest, I just kept adding things into parameters until Visual Studio stopped highlighting everything in an angry red. I added those parameters on it's suggestion.

Comment: Have you subscribed to `ListBox`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: I'm unsure how exactly to do that I guess. I thought I did do it with the `private void lbx_city_SelectedIndexChanged` line.

Comment: @HalcyonTwig - I solved your css grid problem but the question disappeared. If you still need it, repost and reply here and I'll add the answer